# How can I dynamically change validator options after creating in ember-cp-validations?

Tags: ember.js

I need to change 'presence' option from 'true' to 'false' depending on dynamic form state.
If formState == 'a' 'name' field is required, if == 'b' then not, and if I dynamically toggled formState, validator should change its option.

I tried do that, but it didn't help:

```
//form/component.js 
init() {
    this._super(...arguments);

    const Validations = buildValidations({
        name: validator('presence', {
        presence: Ember.computed('formState', function() {
            return this.get('formState') == 'a';
        })
     }),
    });

    // I use ember-validated-form-buffer for buffering changes
    this.set('formValues', formBufferProperty('model', Validations));
}
```

Is there any way to solve it?

Comment: try `model.formState` instead

Comment: No, it doesn't work if I get this property from model or buffered object too

Comment: Use disabled property:

Comment: disabled: Ember.computed.equal('model.formState', 'b')

Answer (score 3):

Just disable this validator by doing so
disabled: Ember.computed.equal('model.formState', 'b')

Answer (score 2):

The answer is to sync state through the model.

```
//form/component.js 
init() {
    this._super(...arguments);

    const Validations = buildValidations({
        name: validator('presence', {
            presence: Ember.computed.equal('model.formState', 'a')
        })
    });

    // I use ember-validated-form-buffer for buffering changes
    this.set('formValues', formBufferProperty('model', Validations));
}
```

But for those who use ember-validated-form-buffer: it is sensitive to imports order and should be above the ember-cp-validations, at least in current versions:

```
"ember-validated-form-buffer": "0.0.1",
"ember-cp-validations": "3.1.2",
```

Comment: What's the way to do so in 2022?